# Remove of multifield items not clearing the fields in cq5 Dialog

Tags: extjs, aem

I am trying to create a component in AEM CQ5 which will generate a quiz module. My requirement is to create a dialog which will allow me to create multiple questions each with multiple answers. My dialog xml is as follows -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        xtype="tabpanel">
        <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
            <categories 
                jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
                title="Questions & Answers">
                <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                    <questions-answers
                        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                        title="Questions & Answers"
                        name="./qasegment"
                        xtype="dialogfieldset">
                            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                                <link
                                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                                    fieldDescription="Click on Add item to add questions. Once question is added, click on Edit Answers to add answers and the destination URLs"
                                    name="./questionsAnswers"
                                    typeHint="String"
                                    xtype="multifield">                         
                                    <fieldConfig 
                                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                        xtype="widgets.configurableQandAfield"/>
                                </link>
                            </items>
                    </questions-answers>
                </items>       
            </categories>
        </items>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

From and xtype:mutlifield, I am referring to a custom extjs widget which is as follows. This will create the (question + question configurations + Add answer multifield ) multifield.

```
/*A global array to save the questions*/

var questionBanks =[];
var myQuestionStore = new CQ.Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    data   : questionBanks,
    id:0,
    fields : ['myId','username']
});

/**
 * @class NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField
 * @extends CQ.form.CompositeField
 * This is a custom widget based on {@link CQ.form.CompositeField}.
 * @constructor
 * Creates a new NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField.
 * @param {Object} config The config object
 */
NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.CompositeField, {

     /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.HiddenField
     */
    hiddenField: null,
    questionHiddenField: null,

     /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    hiddenAnswerTypeField:null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.TextField
     */
    questionText: null,

    questionStyle:null,

    questionStyle1:null,

    answerType:null,

    /**
     * @private
     * @type CQ.Ext.form.FieldSet
     */
    answerSet:null,

    constructor: function(config) {
        config = config || { };
        var defaults = {
            "border": true,
            "layout": "form",
            "labelSeparator": ":",
            "padding": "10px"
        };
        config = CQ.Util.applyDefaults(config, defaults);
        NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField.superclass.constructor.call(this, config);
    },

    // overriding CQ.Ext.Component#initComponent
    initComponent: function() {
        NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

        if(this.itemId == undefined) {
            this.itemId = this.id.split('-')[2];
        }

        // Add a hidden field to hold our result to store.
        this.hiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
            name: this.name
        });
        this.add(this.hiddenField);

        this.questionHiddenField = new CQ.Ext.form.Hidden({
            name: this.name
        });
       // this.add(this.questionHiddenField);

        // Add the link text field and label.
        this.questionText = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
            fieldLabel: 'Question',
            name:'./questionText',
            allowBlank: false,
            emptyText: "Enter the question",
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn:this.updateQuestionHidden
                }
            },
            width: 500,
        });
        this.add(this.questionText);

        this.questionStyle = new CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox({
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',                    
            lazyRender:true,
            mode: 'local', 
            fieldLabel:'Question Style',
            name:'./questionStyle',
            valueField: 'options',
            displayField: 'displayText',
            store: new CQ.Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                id: 0,
                fields: ['options','displayText'],
                data: [
                    ['heading1', 'Heading 1'], 
                    ['heading2', 'Heading 2'],
                    ['questionStyle', 'Question Style 1'],
                    ['answerStyle', 'Answer Style 1'],
                    ['paragraph1', 'Paragraph 1'],
                    ['paragraphImp', 'Paragraph Important'],
                    ['paragraphBold', 'Paragraph Bold'],
                    ['paragraphUrgent', 'Paragraph Urgent'],
                ]
            }),
            listeners: {
                scope: this,
                change: this.updateHidden
            },
        });
        this.add(this.questionStyle);

        this.answerType = new CQ.Ext.form.ComboBox({
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',                    
            lazyRender:true,
            mode: 'local',                            
            allowBlank: false,
            autoSelect: false,
            forceSelection:true,
            fieldLabel:'Answer Type',
            name:'./answerType', 
            valueField: 'options',
            displayField: 'displayText',
            store: new CQ.Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                id: 0,
                fields: ['options','displayText'],
                data: [['text', 'Text Answer'], ['image', 'Image Answer']]
            }),
            value : 'text',
            listeners: {
                change: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn:this.answerTypeselection
                },
                selectionchanged: {
                    scope:this,
                    fn:this.answerTypeselection 
                },
                dialogclose: {
                    scope: this,
                    fn: this.updateHidden
                }
            },
        });
        this.add(this.answerType);

        var fieldsetConfig = CQ.Ext.apply({}, {
           xtype: 'fieldset',
           title: 'Add Answers',
           columnWidth: 0.5,
           name:'./answerFieldSet',
           checkboxToggle: true,
           collapsed: true,
           listeners: {
               expand: {
                    scope: this,
                    fn:this.updateHidden
               }
           },
           items :[
               {
                    xtype: "multifield",
                    name:'./answerStack',                          
                    addItemLabel:"Add an answer",
                    listeners: {
                        change: {
                            scope:this,
                            fn:this.updateHidden
                        },       
                        dialogclose: {
                            scope: this,
                            fn: this.updateHidden
                        }
                    },
                    fieldConfig : {
                        xtype: "apps.ee-web.widgets.configurableAnswer",
                    }
                }
           ]
        });
        this.answerSet = new CQ.Ext.form.FieldSet(fieldsetConfig);
        this.add(this.answerSet);


    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#processInit
    processInit: function (path, record) { 
        this.questionText.processInit(path, record);
        this.questionStyle.processInit(path, record);
        this.hiddenAnswerTypeField.processInit(path, record);
        this.answerSet.processInit(path, record);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#setValue
    setValue: function(value) {
        var link = JSON.parse(value);
        this.itemId = link.itemId;
        this.questionText.setValue(link.questionText);
        this.questionHiddenField.setValue(this.questionText.getValue());
        this.questionStyle.setValue(link.questionStyle);     
        this.answerType.setValue(link.answerType);
        this.answerSet.toggleCollapse(true) ;
        this.answerSet.getComponent(0).setValue(link.answerStack);
        this.hiddenField.setValue(value);
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getValue
    getValue: function() {
        return this.getRawValue();
    },

    // overriding CQ.form.CompositeField#getRawValue
    getRawValue: function() {
         var link = {
            "itemId": this.itemId,
            "questionText": this.questionText.getValue(),
            "questionStyle":this.questionStyle.getValue(),
            "answerType" : this.answerType.getValue(),
            "answerStack" : this.answerSet.findByType('multifield')[0].getValue(),
               };
        return JSON.stringify(link);
    },

     updateQuestionHidden: function() {
        this.questionHiddenField.setValue(this.questionText.getValue());
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    },

    // private
    updateHidden: function() {
        this.hiddenField.setValue(this.getValue());
    },

    answerTypeselection:function(){
        var comboList = this.answerSet.findByType('multifielditem',true);
        console.log(comboList);
        for (var i = 0 ; i < comboList.length ; i ++){
            this.answerSet.remove(comboList[i]);
        }
        this.answerSet.collapse();
        this.answerSet.doLayout();
        this.updateHidden();
    },

});

// Register our new xtype.
CQ.Ext.reg('apps.ee-web.widgets.configurableQandAfield', NirmalWeb.ConfigurableQandAField);
```

One answerType combobox selection, I want to remove the custom multifield elements included in the answerSet Fieldset. I have written the function answerTypeselection to remove the multifield item elements. But,eventhough they are removed from the hidden value field, its not removing from the dialog screen. Am I missing something?? Please guide me. Thanks!

Please help me out. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

If you remove all entries in the multifield, then the questionsAnswers parameter will be empty, which means it will be ignored by the sling Post servlet. If you need the properties to be removed as well you need to add a hidden field with the [@Delete](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/manipulating-content-the-slingpostservlet-servlets-post.html#delete) suffix. This will force Sling to delete the property.

./questionAnswers@Delete=true